# how to add discrete points to slider without using divisions in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to add points to the slider but without using divisions

```dart
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderThemeData(
    trackHeight: 1,
  ),
  child: RangeSlider(
    min: 0.0,
    max: 4.0,
    onChanged: _onChange,
    values: state.value,
    onChangeEnd: _onChangeEnd,
    inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
    activeColor: Theme.of(state.context).accentColor,
  ),
),    `
```

Comment: Have you managed to do it?